# Algebra isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A_1,A_2,B\subset A$ be (if necessary finite dimensional) $k$-algebras (if necessary $k$ can be assumed to be a field) with $A = A_1\oplus A_2$ and $A = A_1 + B$. One may additionally assume that $B\subset A$ have the same $1$. Is it always true that $A_2$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of $B$? (Even with the same $1$ as $B$?)

Comment: Is your direct sum a product of algebras, a coproduct of $k$-algebras, or a coproduct of $k$-modules? If it is a coproduct of $k$-algebras, $A$ may (and usually will) be infinite-dimensional even when $A_1$ and $A_2$ are finite-dimensional.

Comment: I guess, I mean coproduct of algebra without unit. But to be certain, I mean $A = A_1 \oplus A_2$ as $k$-modules and $A_1\cdot A_2 = 0$. (Also note, that $k$ can be assumed to be a field.)

Comment: In fact, I don't even really require that $A_1$ or $A_2$ have a unit. I require for $A$, $B$ a unit, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $A_2$ is isomorphic to a factor:
$$
A_2\cong A/A_1 =(A_1+B)/A_1\cong B/(A_1\cap B).
$$

Comment: So if $B$ is additionally semisimple, it is true.

Comment: @ Peter Patzt: It is true always -- Third isomorphism theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem

Comment: I meant a quotient of $B$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra (not the same unit) if $B$ is semisimple, right?

Comment: @ Peter Patzt: Of course. Since $A_2$ is an ideal, it cannot contain the same unit.